# how to filter log entries by timestamp in gcloud logging command line

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Any one knows how to filter log entries by timestamp in `gcloud` logging command line? From google cloud site - https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging, I learned to read logs by command

`gcloud logging read "resource.type=gce_instance AND logName=projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/syslog AND textPayload:SyncAddress" --limit 10 --format json`

I want to know how to filter by timestamp. I need to read logs in a particular period.

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer in https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library?_ga=2.48552804.-39743739.1582783979

the filter could be like this
timestamp>="2020-07-01T00:00:00Z" AND timestamp<="2020-07-01T00:02:00Z"